# Converting the "chas" variable to a factor with labels "off" and "on"

Tags: r, statistics

How can I convert the "chas" variable to a factor with labels "off" and "on" (referring to the Charles river).

```
>require("MASS")
>?Boston
chas
Charles River dummy variable (= 1 if tract bounds river; 0 otherwise).
> Boston$chas
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [49] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [97] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
[145] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[193] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
[241] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
[289] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[337] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[385] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[433] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[481] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

P.S.: Turns out I have messed up with Boston$chas using factor command and now I have the following! Do you know how can I reset it to the initial value?

```
> Boston$chas
  [1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
 [20] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
 [39] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
 [58] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
 [77] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
 [96] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[115] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[134] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[153] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[172] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[191] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[210] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[229] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[248] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[267] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[286] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[305] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[324] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[343] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[362] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[381] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[400] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[419] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[438] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[457] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[476] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[495] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
Levels: off on
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x<-factor(Boston$chas, labels=c("On", "Off"))
```

or

```
x<-factor(Boston$chas, labels=c("Off", "On"))
```

Comment: What is this error I am receiving? `> Boston$chas<-factor(Boston$chas,labels=c("Off","On"))
Error in factor(Boston$chas, labels = c("Off", "On")) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 0`

Comment: Do you if your answer is correct why I can't draw a barplot afterward? `> Boston$chas<-factor(Boston$chas, labels=c("Off", "On"))
> barplot(Boston$chas)
Error in barplot.default(Boston$chas) : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix`

Comment: @MonaJalal, why not just `plot`, if you want barplot you should provide height, ie cout of on and off , something like `barplot(c(475,35), names.arg=c("Off","On"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapvalues` in the `plyr` package to change the labels on factors:

```
Boston$chas = mapvalues(as.factor(Boston$chas),levels(as.factor(Boston$chas)),c("off","on")) # change the labels of the levels

# dropping and setting levels
Z = as.factor(sample(LETTERS[1:5],20,replace=T))
levels(Z)
Y = as.factor(Z[-which(Z %in% LETTERS[4:5])])
levels(Y)
Y=droplevels(Y) # drop the levels
levels(Y)
levels(Y) = levels(Z) # bring them back
levels(Y)
Y = factor(Y,levels=LETTERS[1:7]) # expand them
levels(Y)
attr(Y,"levels")
attr(Y,"levels") = LETTERS[1:8] # keep expanding them
levels(Y)
require(plyr)
Y = mapvalues(Y,levels(Y),letters[1:8]) # change the labels of the levels
levels(Y)
```

Comment: How can I do it without using external packages?

Comment: create a new variable as in Ananta's post

Comment: Do you know what each row in Boston dataframe mean? (A neighborhood?)

Comment: Roggerman: Do you know how to fix the problem that I have updated in the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
Boston$chas = factor(Boston$chas, levels = c(0, 1), labels=c("off","on"))
```

Without `levels = c(0, 1)` I received an error!

Comment: Works for me with or without the `levels` argument in version 3.0.2.  But I prefer to include the argument.

Answer (score 1):

For your "PS"

When you mess up an object in a package, you've really created a local copy of the object and modified that.  To fix things, simply delete the new object:

```
> Boston$chas <- NA
> head(Boston$chas)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Oops! Looks like I messed up Boston$chas.

But I didn't really modify the original object it.  It still exists in `MASS`

```
> head(MASS::Boston$chas)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Delete the local copy and all is well again:

```
> rm(Boston)
> head(Boston$chas)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: This "PS" should probably have been posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ifelse` and then coerce everything to factor.

```
x <- rbinom(size = 1, n = 100, prob = 0.5)
as.factor(ifelse(x == 1, "yes", "no"))
  [1] no  no  no  no  yes yes yes no  no  no  yes no  yes yes no  yes yes no  no  no  no  yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes
 [31] no  yes no  yes yes no  no  no  no  no  yes yes yes no  yes yes no  no  yes no  yes no  yes yes no  yes no  no  no  yes
 [61] no  yes no  no  no  no  no  yes yes yes no  yes yes yes yes no  no  yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes no  no  yes no 
 [91] yes yes yes no  yes no  yes no  yes no 
Levels: no yes
```